# Sorting a Select_tag with haml and Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, haml, html-select

I am trying to sort the output of a select_tag by the name field

```
%p= select_tag :template, template_options
```

With the following helper code

```
def template_options
  options_from_collection_for_select ExportTemplate.all, :id, :name
end
```

but I can't work out how to do this or whether I should do it in the helper or the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [order](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order)

```
def template_options
  options_from_collection_for_select ExportTemplate.order('name ASC'), :id, :name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends. I tend to use helpers when I'm going to be using the same code in multiple places to DRY (Don't repeat yourself) code up. If you're only using it the once, I'd recommend maybe just placing it inline rather than moving it off to a helper.